# Assigning a value to a variable from a given list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to assign a value to a variable, both are given in a list by my parser. So basically when I get `[x, =, 2]`, I want to assign the value of `2` to `x`.

I am trying to do something like this, but it keeps popping out `false`:

```
assign_value(E, R) :-
   \+ find(=, E, _),
   R = E.
assign_value(E, R) :-
   find(=, E, R1),
   I1 is R1-1,
   I2 is R1+1,
   I3 is R1+2,
   nth0(I1, E, P1),
   nth0(I2, E, P2),
   P1 is P2,
   Result is P1,
   length(E, Length),
   extract(E, 0, I1, ListBefore),
   extract(E, I3, Length, ListAfter),
   append(ListBefore, [Result], Initial),
   append(Initial, ListAfter, Final),
   assign_value(Final, R).
```

Can anyone help? I'm a bit confused, as I am new to Prolog.

Comment: Also, I think that a good idea would be to save the values and the variables in a list of pairs, something like a dictionary of the given program. But I don't really know how to do that

Comment: assert them. Like in: assert( value_of( r, 2 ) ).

Comment: Explain what you mean when you say you want to *assign* 2 to `x`. in Prolog, `x` is an atom and cannot directly be *assigned* a value. However, there are numerous ways to *associate* or *relate* `x` to `2`. One way is using a functor, like @pasabaporaqui suggested: `value_of(x, 2).` Another is to pair it with another kind of term, like `(x=2)` or `[x,2]` (each of these are specialized forms of the first case since `(x=2)` is really `'='(x,2)` and `[x,2]` is really `'.'(x,'.'(2,[]))`. If you use `x-2`, there are Prolog predicates that will regonize it as a key-value pair. Could be handy.

Comment: In your simple example, `assign_value([Var, =, Val], Var-Val).`